# Реализовать функцию

Tags: java

Всем привет.

Не могу создать функцию для решения данной проблемы. Проблема реализовать функцию, которая по целочисленному аргументу 'с' возвращает количество целочисленных решений неравенства.

```
a*a + b*b <= c
a > 0
b > 0
```

То есть

```
lookFor(14) == 8
```

так как подходит 8 пар чисел:

```
(a=1,b=1), (a=1,b=2), (a=1,b=3), (a=2,b=1), (a=2,b=2), (a=2,b=3), (a=3,b=1), (a=3,b=2)
```

Мое решение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Введите число");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int f = in.nextInt();
    // System.out.println("a " + 0);
    int k = 0;
    int c = 0;
    if (f == 0) {
        System.out.println(" Решений нет так как задача равна 0");
    } else {
        for (int a = 0;; a++) {
            if (c <f) {
                for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
                    c = a * a + b * b;
                    System.out.print("(a=" + a + "," + "b=" + b + ")");
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *aa* это *a* в квадрате?

Comment: да. aa это a в квадрате.

Comment: И оно не циклится?

   for (int a = 0;; a++)

Не вижу как из этого цикла выбираться.

Comment: Для начала поправьте цикл:

    for (int a = 0; c < f; a++)

а то он у вас бесконечно работает, и уберите `if (c < f)` из тела цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кстати, ноль — это тоже целое число (если по условиям он недопустим, то меняй начальное условие в for). Вот, на скорую руку набросал:

```
function lookFor($c) {

    $counter = 0;

    for($a=1;$a*$a <= $c; $a++) {

        for($b=1;$b*$b <= $c; $b++) {

            $result = $a*$a+$b*$b;

            if(($result <= $c)) {

                $counter++;
                $out .= '('.$a.', '.$b.') &mdash; Проверка: '.$a.'x'.$a.' + '.$b.'x'.$b.' = '.$result.'<br />';

            }

        }

    }

    $out .= '<strong>Количество пар: </strong>' . $counter;

    return $out;

}

echo lookFor($_GET['c']);
```

А вот вывод запроса lookFor(14):

```
(1, 1) — Проверка: 1x1 + 1x1 = 2
(1, 2) — Проверка: 1x1 + 2x2 = 5
(1, 3) — Проверка: 1x1 + 3x3 = 10
(2, 1) — Проверка: 2x2 + 1x1 = 5
(2, 2) — Проверка: 2x2 + 2x2 = 8
(2, 3) — Проверка: 2x2 + 3x3 = 13
(3, 1) — Проверка: 3x3 + 1x1 = 10
(3, 2) — Проверка: 3x3 + 2x2 = 13
Количество пар: 8
```

Дальше — сам :)

**Обновление**

Сохраняй в файл lookfor.php и вызывай с параметром `с`: `lookfor.php?c=14`

Это, кстати, не количество треугольников прямоугольных, случайно, считаются? :)

Comment: спасибо за решение) не знаю, что это считают, в вопросе не уточнялось, просто  надо было реализовать функцию.